# path('post/<str:slug>/', post_detail, name='post_detail_url') выдает ошибку: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Tags: python, django

Выдаёт ошибку

> SyntxError: invalid syntax у файла urls.py

на 8 строке.

urls.py:

```
    from django.urls import path
    from .views import *

    #some-title

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', posts_list, name='posts_list_url')
        path('post/<str:slug>/', post_detail, name='post_detail_url')
    ]
```

models.py:

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.shortcuts import reverse

    # Create your models here.
    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True)
        body = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True)
        date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return('post_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

        def __str__(self):
            return '{}'.format(self.title)
```

views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from .models import Post

    # Create your views here.
    def posts_list(request):
        posts = Post.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context={'post':post})

    def post_detail(request, slug):
        post = Post.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
        return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context={'post': post})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужна запятая после `path('', posts_list, name='posts_list_url'),`